# Why in Objective-C does doing alloc and init in separate statements cause the object to be released according to the Xcode static analyzer?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-management

I'm making my first steps with Objective-C and have encountered a minor, albeit confusing issue with the static analyzer (Product->Analyze) in XCode 4.1.  I have created a simple Fraction class for rational numbers which I allocate and initialize like this,

```
Fraction* f = [[[ Fraction alloc ] initWithNumerator:3 withDenomimator:5]
                                                               autorelease];
[ f print ];
```

where `print` is a method which just uses `NSLog` to display the fraction, everything works fine. However, if I split the `alloc`/`init` construct apart into two statements (I realize this is non-idiomatic - I'm just trying to understand the machinery) and use manual `release` rather than `autorelease` giving:

```
Fraction* f = [ Fraction alloc ]; // 1. Method returns an Objective-C object with
                                  //    a +1 retain count (owning reference)
[ f initWithNumerator:3 withDenomimator:5]; // 2. Object released
[ f print ]; // 3. Reference-counted object is used after it is released
[ f release ];
```

the program still appears to run without error, but the XCode analyzer gives the warnings in the comments. Why does XCode think the `init` call causes the object to be released?

Thinking through this further as I frame the question I can see that my two programs are not quite equivalent because in the first snippet my pointer `f` is the result of the call to `init` whereas in the second snippet it is the result of `alloc`. So changing my code to,

```
 Fraction* a = [ Fraction alloc ];
 Fraction* f = [ a initWithNumerator:3 withDenomimator:5];
[ f print ];
[ f release ]; // or should it be [ a release ] ?
```

makes it exactly equivalent and the static analyzer stops complaining. So is it possible that `init` can return a different pointer than the one passed to it from `alloc`, rather than just *configuring* the memory it has been passed?  With this code should I pair `[ a release ]` with the `alloc` or `[ f release ]`  with the `init`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is it possible that init can return a different pointer than the one passed to it from alloc, rather than just configuring the memory it has been passed?

absolutely.

> With this code should I pair [ a release ] with the alloc or [ f release ] with the init?

you would assign the value of the initialized object to `f` (as you have). at this point, `a` may be a dangling pointer (if another address is returned). thereore, `f` should be `release`d.

the explanation for this order is that the object may have opted to return a specialized version/variant of itself, and this reallocation happens along the `init...` chain.

silly demonstration:

```
@interface Fraction : NSObject
{
@private
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

@end

static Fraction* EvilFraction = ...;

@implementation Fraction

- (id)initWithNumerator:(int)num denominator:(int)den
{
    self = [super init];
    if (nil != self) {
        if (0 == den){
            [self release];
            return [EvilFraction retain];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to separate calls to `+alloc` and `-init` is explicitly recommended against by Apple, per the documentation for `+[NSObject alloc]`:

> An init... method must be used to complete the initialization process.
>   For example:
>
> TheClass *newObject = [[TheClass alloc] init];

and `-[NSObject init]`:

> In some cases, an init method might release the new object and return
>   a substitute. Programs should therefore always use the object returned
>   by init, and not necessarily the one returned by alloc or
>   allocWithZone:, in subsequent code.

The static analyzer is complaining because it expects that `+alloc` will be paired with `-init`. Because `-init` can release the sender, the static analyzer therefore thinks you're trying to call a method on a deallocated instance.

Answer (score 2):

> So is it possible that `init` can return a different pointer than the one passed to it from `alloc`, rather than just *configuring* the memory it has been passed?

Yes, that's exactly it.  This is also the reason why you don't just call `[super init]` in your initialisers; instead you call it and assign the result to `self` because you aren't necessarily going to get the same instance back.

The relevant documentation is in [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW3).

> With this code should I pair `[ a release ]` with the `alloc` or `[ f release ]`  with the `init`?

If you really want to do something like that, you'd have to check that they aren't equal first, otherwise you'd be over-releasing.  But the real solution is to not split up `alloc` and `init`.  That's the idiomatic way of instantiating objects in Objective C and doing it a different way that you have to add extra code for is counterproductive.