# EASession Leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, external-accessory, eaaccessory

I have an app that connects to an accessory, and the EASession that I create in order to communicate with the accessory leaks when you disconnect the accessory.

When the accessory connects, I get a notification of this and check EAAccessoryManager's accessories collection for an accessory with a certain name that uses a certain protocol.  When I find this I create an EASession object for that accessory with code:

```
-(void) openSession
{
   ...  // finds accessory object

   if (accessory)
   {
      [self closeSession];
      session = [EASession alloc];
      NSLog(@"alloc :: session retainCount: %i", session.retainCount);
      [session initWithAccessory:accessory forProtocol:SmokeSignalsProtocolName]; 
      NSLog(@"init  :: session retainCount: %i", session.retainCount);

      [[session inputStream] open]; 
      [[session outputStream] open]; 

      ... // other logic (pump run loop, etc..)
   }
}

-(void) closeSession
{
    if (session)
    {
       [[session inputStream] close]; 
       [[session outputStream] close]; 
       [session release], session = nil;
    }
}
```

Normally I have the alloc and init on one line, but what I've found (separating it out like this) is that the alloc gives +1 retain count (as you'd expect) **BUT** the `iniWithAccessory:forProtocol:` gives it +3 retain count when I would only expect +2 retainCount from the init method.

The leaks instrument also appears to support this:

[image]

Step by Step look at the leaks instrument:

1. +1 retain count :: `[???Accessory openSession]` - this is where I alloc a new EASession.
2. +1 retain count :: `[EAInputStream iniWithAccessory:forSession:]` The input stream holds a reference back to the owning session.
3. +1 retain count :: `[EAOutputStream initWithAccessory:forSession:]` The output stream holds a reference back to the owning session.
4. +1 retain count :: `[EASession iniWithAccessory:forProtocol:]`  I have no idea why this is increasing the retain count of EASession.  I believe this is responsible for the additional retain count that I can't account for...  Not sure how this is supposed to be balanced.  Is this Apple's bug and I need to call `release` an extra time to balance things....  Very VERY weird.
5. -1 retain count :: `[EAInputStream close]`  Cleans up step #2 above
6. -1 retain count :: `[EAOutputStream close]`  Cleans up step #3 above
7. -1 retain count :: `???Accessory closeSession]` Cleans up step #1 above1

So...  Why am I leaking the EASession object?  What's the proper way to use a EASession object to not leak?

---

### Edit - EADemo Does Not Leak, but ...

[EADemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html) connects to accessories, but it does not leak.  Out of curiosity, I added an extra `[_session retain]` to make it leak so I could follow the malloc history of it in instruments.  It was interesting to see some internal things called that were not called in the malloc history of my app.

[image]

You can see this has `[EAAccessoryInternal removeSession:]` called 3 times.  This was never called in the malloc history of my app.  I think this is key to why my EASession is not being released...

Comment: Regarding splitting the `alloc` and `init`, you might want to read the answers to this question: [Why in Objective-C does doing alloc and init in separate statements cause the object to be released according to the Xcode static analyzer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498388/why-in-objective-c-does-doing-alloc-and-init-in-separate-statements-cause-the-ob). While possibly unrelated, splitting these two is not recommended for the reasons discussed there.

Comment: @BradLarson I appreciate your comment.  I'll put them back together and try things out.  The [EADemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html) appears to work fine without leaking.  It also has retain count of 4 after the `alloc` and `initWithAccessory:forProtocol:`, but before releasing the `EASession` has a retain count of 1...  So I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I have been seeing this too. Let me know if you found the answer!

Comment: Have you tried to setDelegate and scheduleInRunLoop before stream open?

Answer (score 1):

I know this discussion is quite old now but I had exactly the same problem recently using ARC e.t.c. I've found that one way around it is by just not closing the input or output streams. Just have a class that deals with all input e.t.c and forward on the data on request to other parts of your application. You can re-alloc init the EASession object with no complaints from XCode so I'm assuming the old EASession is dealloc ed OK as it's no longer referenced by my APP.
I haven't checked the leaks yet however.

Answer (score 1):

While the demo does it the other way round, I managed to fix this leak by calling the input and output close methods **after** removing them from the run loop and setting their delegate to nil.