# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on alloc

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

If this issue has been posted before, I can't find it.

I'm attempting to allocate and initialize an instance of NSString in the initialization method of a subclass of NSOperation (for use with NSOperationQueue).  The NSString pointer is an ivar (not a property).

The program crashes with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)".

To isolate the problem, I've separated the alloc and init functions.  The main thread is crashing on:

`m_myString = [NSString alloc];`

The code is in an "if" block:

```
if (someCondition)
{
  m_myString = [NSString alloc];
  m_myString = [m_myString initWithCString:aCharPointer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
else
{
  m_myString = [NSString alloc];
  m_myString = [m_myString initWitCString:aDifferentCharPointer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Examining the thread shows that it's crashing on objc_release.  I don't understand why release would be called on an object *in the allocation method*, but that seems to be the case...

It's worth mentioning that I successfully alloc and init another instance variable NSString in the same method *before the if block*.

Has anyone else run into this before, and if so, how'd you solve it?

I'd be glad to give more info upon request.

Comment: `objc_release` could be called on the *previous* reference stored in `m_myString`, have you looked at that?

Comment: Interesting thought, but I'm 99% sure that's not the case, since this is occurring in the initialization function.  This instance of NSString hasn't ever stored a value previously, and calling alloc to set the pointer is actually the first time I even access  the pointer.

Comment: @trojanfoe found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498388/why-in-objective-c-does-doing-alloc-and-init-in-separate-statements-cause-the-ob) as a possible duplicate. What that tells you is that your code change while tracking down the problem may also have introduced a `release`, I.e. you may have inadvertently obscure the issue.

Comment: @CRD Huh?  how am involved, other than closing this question as duplicate earlier?

Comment: @trojanfoe - just giving you credit for finding the other question, it's relevant but I don't think it's a dupe.

Comment: @CRD Yeah maybe. The issue is so easy to avoid with `m_myString = someCondition ? @(cCharPointer) : @(aDifferentCharPointer);`, however...

Comment: This is a simplification.  there's actually several nested if / else if / else statements, and m_myString takes on a different value depending on the state of the software.

Additionally, it crashes in objc_release if I pair alloc and init together, and even if I call a class method of NSString that returns an object I don't own, such as `[NSString stringWithCString: encoding:];`  It even crashes if I simply assign it to a string literal, like `m_myString = @"test";`

Out of curiosity, why would using `m_myString = someCondition ? @(charPointer) : @(diffCharPointer); make any difference?

Comment: @LiftAndMath - The reason we've given you suggestions for things to look at is because there is not enough info here to provide an *answer*. That assigning a literal causes the same issue does point to the variable itself, and then the object it is part of, etc... You're going to have to dig further and/or generate a smaller complete sample with the error that you can post so others can try to reproduce it. There is nothing wrong *per se* with your original code, and breaking the `alloc` and `init` up as you later did, while not recommended, shouldn't cause a problem either. Good hunting!